# how to show array received from server in Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to show the user an array with the names that I get from the server. To allow the user to select the desired item from the list.

If I just write an array, then everything works.

```
   let liste=  
    [ 
       { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
       { label: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 } 
    ]

 <Autocomplete
              disablePortal
              id="combo-box-demo"
              options={liste}
              onChange={(event , newevent) => {
              setBehoerdeName(newevent) }}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
```

[image]

but if I get data from the server, it gives an error
although I get an array too.

```
 let allDates = async function getAllDate() {
        let list = await axios.get("/myWay")
          if (list.data.success) {
            let finalList = list.data.json.map(({name1, ort, plz}) => ({name1, ort, plz}));
            return finalList
          } else {
            return null
          }
      };

 <Autocomplete
              disablePortal
              id="combo-box-demo"
              options={allDates }
              onChange={(event , newevent) => {
              setBehoerdeName(newevent) }}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Behörden" />}
   />
```

i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: options.filter is not a function
```

I tried to write data to a function and call it in options but the result is the same.

Comment: You can try printing the allDates after calling getAllDate() function and check if it's an array or something else

Comment: (13321) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
it is array

Comment: maybe the array is too big so it's not being called?

Comment: No that's should not be the error. according to your error options is not an array therefore options.fillter is not a function. Can you create a sandbox ,github repo or some reproductible example so that i can debug